# How do I complete the fourth maze in the garden of the Parfum Palace?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I want to know how to complete the fourth maze in the garden of the Parfum Palace in Pokemon Y. I know how to complete the first three mazes in the garden but the fourth one is a mystery.

Could anyone please tell me how to solve the fourth maze?

Comment: what is it that you want to know, exactly? If your not actually asking a question, your question is automatically off topic for Arqade.

Answer (score 5):

From [Cherrygrove on psypoke forums](http://psypokes.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=501391&sid=a63b9f4d6e970d9405548a5b178cc69c#p501391):

> [image: the fourth maze]
>
> Refer to the image above.
>
> At the start of the puzzle, Furfrou will be in Square 2. Ask Shauna to
> wait in Square 1. Next, take the red path from Square 1 to Square 2.
> Furfrou will run to Square 3. Take Shauna to Square 2 and ask her to
> wait there. Finally, take the Blue path from Square 2 to Square 3 and
> Furfrou will be trapped.
>
> I hope this helps.

Comment: What question are you interpreting from the above post? If there is an obvious question being implied, it would be a good idea to edit it in, to prevent the question closure.

Comment: @Timelord64 There's only one 'mansion' (like the OP originally called it) where there are 4 mazes and you have to solve it by cornering a Furfrou. The first mazes are relatively straightfroward, while the 4th requires moving an element into the maze (Shauna) to reach the goal. There are no other places in the game involving both a mansion and 4 mazes. I really don't know what I could edit in the question to make it clearer than it already is.

Comment: In contrast, I could change the question wording completely, add images and so on, but I never did something like that before on any SE site, because that would move towards too drastic changes...

Comment: At the end of the day, OP is not asking a question. If you think there is a question, and in your perception it is quite obvious, you are free to edit it in. Put "added obvious question to prevent closure" or similar as the edit summary, and post a comment saying "i think it is obvious you meant to ask <question>, so im adding it in to prevent the question being closed. Feel free to rollback the edit, but make sure you add your intended question, or this question is likely to be closed"

Comment: As it is, this might be a good answer. But since the question was obviously going to be closed for not having a question, answering as it is is frowned upon. If this question does end up being deleted, having answers makes more work for the mods.